# JS/PHP: How to implement a live and persistent counter?

Tags: php, javascript, counter, persistent

I have a js function which once acted upon (user clicks), it'll display an input field, which the user will add some text and save it to the db. There is a counter so every time the field is saved, the db will have another entry, rather than update the previous one. The problem is that the counter is in js, so whenever the browser reloads the counter is reset and the entry is being updated rather than added.

In order to resolve this I thought about saving the current figure to the db and retrieve it every time the page is loaded. Update it once the user clicks and save it again at the end of the session. I'm finding this a very ugly solution. Alternatively I could save the counter in a cookie, but again, not very elegant.

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why not have it as an auto increment field in the db? then you wouldnt have to handle the counter at all.