# How to create an auto increment field in WordPress db

Tags: mysql, wordpress, auto-increment

How can I create an auto increment field in WordPress db? I'm writing a plugin and would like to create this field to be used as reference that will be used elsewhere in the plugin. I've been searching but haven't found it yet. Not specific to WP that is. Any suggestions? This is related to this question: [JS/PHP: How to implement a live and persistent counter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884761/js-php-how-to-implement-a-live-and-persistent-counter/16884996?noredirect=1#16884996)

Comment: what do you know about mysql? wordpress doesn't have db engine in it

Comment: What do you mean by auto increment? You need to specify when do you need this field incremented (WP Hooks and events)? And you need also to tell us what this field is related to (user, post...)? because WP allow creation of many types of meta fields.

Comment: @DanielA.White not much, I'm afraid, but I can research and do purely with mysql. I was wondering whether there was some particular way/functions that's preferred in WP's case.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces Basically I have a js function hooked to a WP function. Every time the user clicks on a link, a input is generated and the name attribute of this field would auto increment. The user would then add some text which will be saved in the db. I need to reference this so next time the user add another field, it'll match to what's being saved in the db. This approach has two issues: If I do this in js alone, the counter will reset once the page is reloaded. Secondarily I need the auto increment matched up with the field saved in the db so I can query this data dynamically